# Please help me to split the complex header string into items

Tags: python, python-re

Please help me to use Python regular expressions to split this header into the items

```
TITLE="D:\Experiments2021\iai_0107_\exp1_\Analysis\exp1_006014.T000.D000.P001.H000.L.vec" VARIABLES="X mm", "Y mm", "U m/s", "V m/s", "CHC", DATASETAUXDATA Application="PIV" DATASETAUXDATA SourceImageWidth="4008" DATASETAUXDATA SourceImageHeight="2672" DATASETAUXDATA MicrometersPerPixelX="85.809998" DATASETAUXDATA MicrometersPerPixelY="85.809998" DATASETAUXDATA LengthUnit="mm" DATASETAUXDATA OriginInImageX="0.000000" DATASETAUXDATA OriginInImageY="0.000000" DATASETAUXDATA MicrosecondsPerDeltaT="50.000000" DATASETAUXDATA TimeUnit="ms" DATASETAUXDATA SecondaryPeakNumber="0" DATASETAUXDATA DewarpedImageSource="0" ZONE I=124, J=82, F=POINT
```

I cannot figure out how to separate the repeated pattern of the type:

```
DATASETAUXDATA MicrosecondsPerDeltaT="50.000000" DATASETAUXDATA TimeUnit="ms
```

into:

```
header = {'MicrosecondsPerDeltaT':50.0000, 'TimeUnit':'ms', ...}
```

and so on.

Thanks in advance,
Alex

Comment: What are we looking at? What header? What's the format?

Answer (score 1):

I *assume* you want to create a dictionary with key value pairs matching that pattern. If that is what you want, something like this will do the trick:

```py
import re

text="""
TITLE="D:\Experiments2021\iai_0107_\exp1_\Analysis\exp1_006014.T000.D000.P001.H000.L.vec" VARIABLES="X mm", "Y mm", "U m/s", "V m/s", "CHC", DATASETAUXDATA Application="PIV" DATASETAUXDATA SourceImageWidth="4008" DATASETAUXDATA SourceImageHeight="2672" DATASETAUXDATA MicrometersPerPixelX="85.809998" DATASETAUXDATA MicrometersPerPixelY="85.809998" DATASETAUXDATA LengthUnit="mm" DATASETAUXDATA OriginInImageX="0.000000" DATASETAUXDATA OriginInImageY="0.000000" DATASETAUXDATA MicrosecondsPerDeltaT="50.000000" DATASETAUXDATA TimeUnit="ms" DATASETAUXDATA SecondaryPeakNumber="0" DATASETAUXDATA DewarpedImageSource="0" ZONE I=124, J=82, F=POINT
"""

result = re.findall(r"DATASETAUXDATA \w+=\"[\w\.]+\"", text)
dict = {}

for item in result:
    pair = item.replace("DATASETAUXDATA ", "")
    key_value = pair.split("=")
    dict[key_value[0]] = key_value[1].replace("\"", "")

print(dict)

# prints {'Application': 'PIV', 'SourceImageWidth': '4008', 'SourceImageHeight': '2672', 'MicrometersPerPixelX': '85.809998', 'MicrometersPerPixelY': '85.809998', 'LengthUnit': 'mm', 'OriginInImageX': '0.000000', 'OriginInImageY': '0.000000', 'MicrosecondsPerDeltaT': '50.000000', 'TimeUnit': 'ms', 'SecondaryPeakNumber': '0', 'DewarpedImageSource': '0'}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try below code

```py
import re
r = re.compile('DATASETAUXDATA MicrosecondsPerDeltaT="(?P<MicrosecondsPerDeltaT>\d*[.,]?\d*)" DATASETAUXDATA TimeUnit="(?P<TimeUnit>.*)"')
s = '''DATASETAUXDATA MicrosecondsPerDeltaT="50.000000" DATASETAUXDATA TimeUnit="ms"'''
output = r.match(s).groupdict()
print(output)
# {'MicrosecondsPerDeltaT': '50.000000', 'TimeUnit': 'ms'}
```